# How do i change the view path for make:auth controllers in laravel?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

How do I change the routes of the authentication components which are created with `make:auth`?

`routes/web.php` contains

```
Auth::routes();
```

How do I change the path for register, for example, to `/account` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's `Auth::routes();` uses a function `auth()` defined in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`

You can copy the content of this function and paste it directly in your `web.php` file and update as you want.

```
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

So here you can change the route for `/register`. Don't forget to remove the `Auth::routes()` helper from the web.php when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Auth controller you can override the redirection

```
   class RegisterController extends Controller
{
  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Register Controller
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
  | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
  | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
  |
  */

  use RegistersUsers;

  /**
  * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $redirectTo = '/';
```